# Extend a class using generics for a specific type

Tags: java, generics

I am wondering. I have a `class OccList<T>`. I am fine with OccList holding any object, but I want to do more if T is a String, or if T is an integer.

Is there any way I can use the same name while doing it? My solution thus far is to create a new class `class StringOccList extends OccList<String>`. Optimally I'd like to be able to use `OccList<String>` and let java create the appropriate class according to the type used, much like method signatures work. Is it possible? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Is there a compelling reason why the class needs to be genericized? In some cases simply providing overloaded methods is more than sufficient.

Comment: "let java create the appropriate class according to the type used" - I don't think this is really possible, which subclass to instantiate for a given variable is not something the compiler will decide for you.

Comment: @millimoose, if I understand what you mean, I believe it is possible. Please see the examples in my answer

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki Your example won't create subclasses of the generic class. (E.g. it can't create `StringOccList`.) It in fact does nothing useful at all, not with the diamond operator in Java 7.

Comment: @Perception sounds a very good idea. So I can just overload the `add(T)` method for example? I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Yes well, the problem with method overloading is this. If I create a method `add(String)`, then this method always exists, even when someone has created `new OccList<Double>();`. Also in order to put items in the internal structure (which is a `List<T>`) through the String specific method, I have to explicitly cast them to T again.

Comment: @Andreas - you misunderstand me. I am not suggesting a combination of genericization and overloading, I'm suggesting one over the other. Aka, if your class does not *really* need to be generic, then don't make it so, simply provide overloaded versions of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a different class, unless you want the added functionality to be part of the base class.

Think about it; lets say you have a method `printAll` that calls `System.out.println` on all the contents of the list. Where is the method going to go?

1. You only want the method to be callable if it's a `String`. Then it **cannot** be part of the base class (because otherwise it would be defined in the base class), so you need to use a different class like `StringOccList`
2. It's okay if the method is callable in the base class. You can write it so that (in the case of `String`) it calls `T.toString` on all members, or you can have the method throw an exception if T isn't the appropriate type.

That's what it means to be "generic" - the class will work for any kind of inner type. If it won't work for any kind of inner type, then it's not generic anymore!

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I was wondering if I could somehow overload that, much like you say `foo(String)` and `foo(Integer)` for methods. I guess not!

Comment: Well you can certainly do `foo(T)` and implement functionality based on what T is in the baseclass...

Comment: Can I? Is there a way to find out what T is? Because it seemed like I cannot do `T.getClass()` for examples, or instanceof etc.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could make use of the one place where Java infers types, that is method returns. Imagine you want an `OccList` of `String`, but you don't want to do this

```
OccList<String> list = new OccList<String>();
```

Well, then you just write up a method to do that. Like this:

```
public static <E> OccList<E> newOccList(){
    return new OccList();
}
```

and invoke it like this:

```
OccList<String> stringList = newOccList();
OccList<Integer> integerList = newOccList();
OccList<File> fileList = newOccList();
```

It'll work for any generic type you need.

This is used in the Google Guava library, please refer to it [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

Comment: `Occlist<String> list = new OccList<>();` is the Java 7 shortcut that does pretty much what the type inference hack accomplishes (http://ideone.com/AmPwiu), which I believe is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help, unless I use it as a factory method? For example `newOccList(Object obj)` and then I create the appropriate object according to the class of obj?

Comment: Yes, I believe I have misunderstood your question. In your problem the simplest solution would be a factory method, so you can control the instances yourself